# Upgrading Fedora to Current Version - Dependent Applications Concerns

Tags: mysql, php, fedora

Is it possible to upgrade to Fedora 11 and still keep the server functional (it's running Fedora Core release 6 now, with MySQL 5.0, PHP 5.1 and Apache 2.2)?  I have a Customer Relationship Management system on there and it is required on a daily basis.  I am trying to figure out if I should upgrade (and whether that will cause huge problems) or if I should start over with a new OS (like Ubuntu) and install the CRM fresh, with updated version of MySQL, PHP, Apache, etc.  I ask because I am not really the sysadmin, but have but put in charge of this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really talk to your CRM vendor, they will be able to tell you if there are incompatibilities in the new versions, as well as give you some guidance as far as the upgrade process where their application is concerned.

Also, without know which CRM you are talking about we can't possibly give you any kind of advice besides talk to the vendor.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I am in the position to buy the Professional version of my CRM, and at this point I will have support.  I was just doing some leg work before then.  It looks like a complete makeover of this server will be the best way to go, along with integrating the new version of the CRM.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would move over to CentOS 5 instead of going to a newer version of Fedora. You will still have the same issue regarding lifespan if you stick with Fedora, and F11 is going to go out of support soon enough.